# Permissions problem from running rsync through a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos

I have an Automator 'Quick Action' which simply runs a shell script (using bash) which comprises of a single rsync command. I've assigned a keyboard shortcut to this from System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Since updating to Catalina, I'm getting a permissions problem like shown in the second last comment here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126497.

Basically, I can run my rsync command in Terminal and it'll work fine. I can also open the Automator file and run it from there and it'll work fine. But running it from a keyboard shortcut throws the permissions error.

I've granted full disk access to both rsync and my quick action file, but to no effect. The last comment in that link mentions that you need to also grant full disk access to the program that calls your program (in their case it was cron), but I don't know what the calling program is in my case.

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Automator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.automator.runner.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.automator.runner`

Comment: Thanks @zrzka, I gave that file full disk access but unfortunately the problem persists 